# Regular expression to remove link in String in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, regex, macos, nsregularexpression

I have bunch of strings I receive from service and need to alter the text to extract and remove 3 types of link as mentioned below

```
anchor - [anchor:info]Account Details[/anchor]
action -  [action:contact]Contact info[/anchor]
link-to - [link-to:register]Create An Account[/link-to]
```

Example full length text from service:

1. "There's a problem with your `[anchor:info]Account Details[/anchor]`."
2. "There's a problem with your `[anchor:rewards]Sign Up For Rewards[/anchor]`."
3. "We didn't recognize this account. Please re-enter your email or `[link-to:register]Create An Account[/link-to]`."

And the expected result should be:

1. "There's a problem with your Account Details."
2. "There's a problem with your Sign Up For Rewards."
3. "We didn't recognize this account. Please re-enter your email or Create An Account."

I figured I will use replacingOccurrences function to achieve this. But I haven't cracked the regular expression for my required format.

```
let aString = "There's a problem with your [anchor:info]Account Details[/anchor]."
let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: "regex here", with: " ", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
```

I can either have 3 separate regex to match the 3 cases or have one regex which can handle below:

```
[any_link_type:any_identifier]Any Text[/any_link_type]
```

Can some regex gurus help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern `^([^[]+)\[([^:\]]+)[^\]]*\]([^[]+)\[\/\2\]`

And replace it with `\1\3`.

Explanation:

`^` - beginning of the string

`([^[]+)` - match one or more characters other than `[` and store in capturing group

`\[` - match `[` literally

`([^:\]]+)` - match one or more characters other than `:` or `]` and store in capturing group

`[^\]]*` - match zero or more characters other than `]`

`\]` - match `]` literally

`([^[]+)` - match one or more characters other than `[` and store in capturing group

`\[\/` - match `[/` literally

`\2` - match the same text as was matched in second capturing group (so it matches closing tag, like `anchor`)

`\]` - match `]` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jv5N9s/1)

Answer (score 0):

Got it :) this regex will work for my requirement: \[.*?\]

```
let linkString = "We didn't recognize this account. Please re-enter your email or [link-to:register]Create An Account[/link-to]."

let newLinkString = linkString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\[.*?\\]", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get the expected output.

**Swift 4:-**

```
let aString = "There's a problem with your [anchor:info]Account Details[/anchor]."
let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\[.*?\\]", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
print(newString) //There's a problem with your Account Details.
```

**Swift 5:-**

```
let aString = "There's a problem with your [anchor:info]Account Details[/anchor]."
let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: #"\[.*?\]"#, with: " ", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
print(newString) //There's a problem with your Account Details.
```